# Can populations of different sizes be compared sensibly?

Tags: modeling, biostatistics, population

I am new here but have a question about population comparisons.

I am trying counting pollen grains using an Scanning Electronic Microscope (SEM). I want to compare the abundance of a certain type of pollen between two samples. The SEM is able to produce a .tif of the same sized area for both samples (in terms of pixels) so the area in which the pollen will be counted is the same for both samples. However, the actual number of total pollen grains in that area may differ between samples due to the preparation methods.

What I want to know is, if you have a total of 250 pollen grains in sample A counting area but 700 pollen grains in sample B counting area, can these samples be compared sensibly, irrespective of the actual number of pollen grains of interest? Would it be better to present the relative abundance of the interestingredients pollen with respect to the overall number of grains in that area, can you take the  difference in population size within that area into account by normalising or would it be better to use a ratio of i.e. pollen of interest/total pollen?

I should mention that the samples are prepared in the same way with the assumption being that any sub-sampled area is indicative of the sample as a whole. The issue is that I don't have the starting weights of the samples, so any mass corrections are out of the question, hence the area plan.

Which seems the most sensible, if any at all? I am open to any and all suggestions.